# Multiple ajax calls through jquery fails with callback was not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, deferred

I'n having a web page with a html table. 
In every row i have a link to some restful service which is on another server.

When i press the button in one row the ajax call is executing just fine and i get the answer.
I'm trying to call all the services from the table in a loop.
I add the calls in javascript array and then use **when** and **apply** to execute them.

Only one of the calls executed and return data back.
Checking the network in inspect i can see the results from restful services just fine but jquery keep returns callback was not called.

I know that i'm doing something wrong with deferred objects but i can't understand how to to use them correctly.

You can see the single call page at
http://distml.kstergiou.net/single.html

and the batch version at
http://distml.kstergiou.net/batch.html

Can you help me find what am i doing wrong?

The code in batch page (jquery and html) is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var response = [];
    var restArray = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#execBatch').click(function(){
            $('#tblMethods tr').each(function(){
                var self = $(this);
                var inp = self.find('.execSingle');
                var urlStr = inp.attr("data-exec");
                var rowNum = inp.attr('data-rownum');
                var clfData = '';

                if (urlStr != undefined) {
                    restArray.push( $.ajax({
                            cache: true,
                            type: "GET",
                            url: urlStr,
                            data: clfData,
                            contentType: "application/javascript",
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            crossDomain: true,
                            jsonp: 'callback',
                            jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                            success: function (data) {
                                response.push(data.strResult);
                                console.log('success');
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                console.log(error);
                                response[rowNum] = 'Error<br>Status<br>' + status + 'Error Message<br>' + error;
                            }
                        })
                    )
                }
            });

            $.when.apply(null, restArray).done(function(){
                console.log(arguments);
                    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                        console.log(arguments[i][0].strResult);
                    }
                }).fail( function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                    console.log(status + ' --- ' + error);
            });
        });

        $('.showSingle').click(function () {
            var self = $(this);
            var rowNum = self.attr('data-rownum');
            $('#output').html('<pre>' + response[rowNum] + '</pre>');
        });

    }); // document.ready

</script>

    </head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <table id="tblMethods" style="border:1px solid blue; width:100%" class="table">
                <thead style="border:1px solid green; background-color: #e0e0e0">
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Server</th>
                    <th>Classifier</th>
                    <th>Filter</th>
                    <th>DataFile</th>
                    <th>Evaluate</th>
                    <th>numFolds</th>
                    <th style="display:none">execute</th>
                    <th style="display:none">completed</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr><td>0</td><td>Server 1 - locahost</td><td>Naive Bayes</td><td>No Filter</td><td>Anneal</td><td>false</td><td>10</td><td><input type="button" value="Exec" id="execSingle0" data-rownum="0" data-exec="http://clouddom.ergologic.gr:8080/com.alchemist.ml/rowid/0/clfid/0/filterid/0/fileid/0/eval/false/numfolds/10/" class="btn btn-xs btn-success execSingle" style="display:none"></td><td><input type="button" value="Show" id="showSingle0" data-rownum="0" class="showSingle btn btn-xs btn-info"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td>Server 1 - locahost</td><td>SMO</td><td>No Filter</td><td>Anneal</td><td>false</td><td>10</td><td><input type="button" value="Exec" id="execSingle1" data-rownum="1" data-exec="http://clouddom.ergologic.gr:8080/com.alchemist.ml/rowid/1/clfid/1/filterid/0/fileid/0/eval/false/numfolds/10/" class="btn btn-xs btn-success execSingle" style="display:none"></td><td><input type="button" value="Show" id="showSingle1" data-rownum="1" class="showSingle btn btn-xs btn-info"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>2</td><td>Server 1 - locahost</td><td>J48</td><td>No Filter</td><td>Anneal</td><td>false</td><td>10</td><td><input type="button" value="Exec" id="execSingle2" data-rownum="2" data-exec="http://clouddom.ergologic.gr:8080/com.alchemist.ml/rowid/2/clfid/7/filterid/0/fileid/0/eval/false/numfolds/10/" class="btn btn-xs btn-success execSingle" style="display:none"></td><td><input type="button" value="Show" id="showSingle2" data-rownum="2" class="showSingle btn btn-xs btn-info"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>3</td><td>Server 1 - locahost</td><td>RandomForest</td><td>No Filter</td><td>Anneal</td><td>false</td><td>10</td><td><input type="button" value="Exec" id="execSingle3" data-rownum="3" data-exec="http://clouddom.ergologic.gr:8080/com.alchemist.ml/rowid/3/clfid/8/filterid/0/fileid/0/eval/false/numfolds/10/" class="btn btn-xs btn-success execSingle" style="display:none"></td><td><input type="button" value="Show" id="showSingle3" data-rownum="3" class="showSingle btn btn-xs btn-info"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>4</td><td>Server 1 - locahost</td><td>RandomTree</td><td>No Filter</td><td>Anneal</td><td>false</td><td>10</td><td><input type="button" value="Exec" id="execSingle4" data-rownum="4" data-exec="http://clouddom.ergologic.gr:8080/com.alchemist.ml/rowid/4/clfid/9/filterid/0/fileid/0/eval/false/numfolds/10/" class="btn btn-xs btn-success execSingle" style="display:none"></td><td><input type="button" value="Show" id="showSingle4" data-rownum="4" class="showSingle btn btn-xs btn-info"></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
        <input type=button name="BuildAll" id="execBatch" class="btn btn-xs btn-info execBatch" value="Build All"/>
    <hr>

    <div id="output" style="border:1px solid red"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is that if you want multiple JSONP calls in flight at the same time that you have to let jQuery dynamically create the callback name rather than you specify it.  If you specify the callback name, then all the ajax calls are going to use the same callback name and things will get very confused because jQuery can't tell which response is which.

Comment: First thing to change is the way `response` is added to - use `response[rowNum] = ...` for both success and error. Then, change the call pattern to make the ajax requests sequentially, by constructing a .then() chain.

Answer (score -1):

AS you use jsonp, the function `callback`is called on return of the ajax request. But this function is not defined in your code. You need to implement it.

Comment: In JSONP, it is the server which creates the callback function in the returned script.

Comment: @jfriend00 In his provided link, a method call was returned but not the method itself, leading to the error described above. (At least, when the example was working)